# Creating Javascript object from JQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing

Currently I'm unit testing the following code:

```
if ($(selectedElement).innerText == 'blah')
{
    // do something
}
```

with selectedElement being an anchor object selected from the UI.

In my test code, I have created a DOM structure which has that anchor in the proper position ready to be selected.  The problem here is that since selectedElement is originally a javascript object, I need to convert the anchor I got from the DOM structure (which is a JQuery object) in order to get into the above condition.

I have tried the following, with no success:

```
// DOM structure using HtmlDoc
/*:DOC += <span id='testSpan' class='testSpanClass'><a href='#' id='selectedElem'>blah</a></span> */
selectedElement = $('#selectedElem')[0];
```

My goal is to be able to use a normal Javascript object to satisfy the condition, and also be able to switch it back to a jQuery object to satisfy conditions further down the function.  But if there is a better approach I'll give it a go.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to go about this problem?

EDIT: Is there a solution that does not require changing of the code?  selectedElement is actually a global variable.

Thanks.

Comment: +1 for unit testing your code :)

Comment: $(selectedElement).innerText is invalid code .. $(selectedElement) is a wrapped set/array of objects .. innerText is not a property of that .. use $(selectedElement).text()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what browser you are testing in, but `innerText` is an IE only property. Since you are already using jQuery, I would suggest you just call the .text() method on the selected element like this:

```
selectedElement = $('#selectedElem')[0]; // Get DOM element

if ($(selectedElement).text() == 'blah')
{
    // do something
}
```

You're method of getting the DOM object is fine: $('#selectedElem')[0] or $('#selectedElem').get(0) are equivalent, but the first one is faster in large loops.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work.  Also, I would avoid changing the code as selectedElement is a global variable also used somewhere else (as updated in the question).

Comment: What didn't work? (I updated my code to reflect not changing the global variable). If you have a valid DOM element, $(el).text() will return the `innerText` so to speak.

Comment: What if I'm not allowed to change 'innerText'?

Comment: `innerText` is an Internet Explorer only property. It will only work in IE, other browsers have different properties. I think Firefox has `textContent`. Do you mean you can't change the value or you can't change the use of the property?

Comment: I have to use the expression $(selectedElement).innerText.  This is in the source code which I'm not allowed to modify.

Comment: which explains why FF keeps returning undefined for innerText for me. After discovering jQuery, I really lost touch with javascript!

Comment: @BeraCim then your expression will always fail, which is the point of unit tests. The source code is incorrect if that is the format they are using. `$(selectedElement)` returns a jQuery wrapped DOM element. The jQuery object does not have an `.innerText` property and will thus, always fail.

Answer (score 2):

can you use jquery's .html() ?

```
if ($(selectedElement).html() == 'blah')
{
    // do something
}
```

otherwise, without changing code:

```
var selectedElement = $('#selectedElem')[0];

if (selectedElement.innerHTML == 'blah')
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: `.html()` would not be the equivalent of `.innerText`. `.text()` would be what they would want.

Comment: After a quick test to make sure, it seems to work either way. But I was of the understanding that .html() was for anything between html tags.

Comment: If I can change the code, yes this works perfect.  What if I cannot change the code?  Are there anyway to write tests to actually get into the condition?

Comment: Hey Nick, you are right, in this case they would be the same. But if there were any child elements it would be a different result.

Comment: @BeraCim try my edit. 

@dcneiner Yeah, it would return everything between the anchor tags. I'm just used to innerHTML (like in my edit) working on this and not innerText which would be undefined, so I think of .html()

Comment: Code cannot be changed... so $(selectedElement).innerText must stay.  This is why I found the problem very tricky as I can only write test to try to pass the condition.  selectedElement is a html anchor object, not a jQuery object.  And to make matters worse... this is the line of code after the condition: var sth = $(selectedElement).parents('span.className')[0];

Comment: In that case, I don't think it's possible. $(selectedElement).innerText just isn't going to work. innerText is not a property for a jQuery object.

Comment: @Nick right on. The point of testing is writing _failing_ tests, then _fixing_ the code to make the test past. Looks like we have the first part working... the _failing_ part. :)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's get method returns the original DOM elements for that jQuery object.
I think perhaps you need to use `$('#selectedElem').get(0)`